# How to handle particular event by the dynamic created button in sencha touch

Tags: html, extjs, sencha-touch-2

i have created six buttons dynamically using initialize function,also i have assigned different id's to each buttons dynamically,I want to handle event for each button,When i click  each of the different button  i am getting alert message of sixth button id,How to handle particular button event. Thank you

```
Ext.define("DynamicButton.view.Main", {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
initialize: function () {
var me = this;
me.names = ['Button1', 'Button2', 'Button3', 'Button4', 'Button5', 'Button6'];
var toolBar = Ext.create('Ext.Toolbar', {
docked: "bottom"
});
this.add(toolBar);

for (var i = 0; i < me.names.length; i++) {
var name = me.names[i];
var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
id: 'Btn' + name,
html: name,
handler: function() {
alert(button.id);
},
scope: this
});
toolBar.add(button);
}
},
config: {
}
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using Ext.widget() instead of Ext.create() for the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also access the button through the params of the handler function :

```
handler: function (button, event) { 
    console.log(button.id);
}
```

I might be useful if you want to change the scope.

Hope this helps

Comment: I wasn't sure what arguments the handler function passed. But those are the arguments the typical "tap" callbacks use so this is a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of scope. "button" in this case isn't what you think it is.

In this case, you might want to try:

`this.id`

"this" in this instance refers to the instance of the button that was clicked.